# Get website current UICulture in handler.ashx

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, localization, handler, globalization

I have a handler that shows user a message (this is called by jquery load() ) . 
This is a multi-languages website .

On page load I'm setting `Page.UICulture` based on `lang` query string. And all language dependent contents are saved in global resources.

Now when I call handler, in that handler I'm using `Resources.ResourceName.KeyName` to get proper message. But it's not working. It just reads from default resource.

Comment: Are you passing the lang parameter in the querystring when you call the handler.ashx?

Comment: no , Lang querystring is sent to page that calls handler later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be setting `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`. The documentation for `Page.UICulture` which you are using states this:

> This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not
>   intended to be used directly from your code.

And you should do so inside `InitializeCulture`, as per "To set the culture and UI culture for an ASP.NET Web page programmatically" on [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) page, which also provides an example.